# Load some keys with arrays of values into pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have some data in the following key value form which I need to load into Pig.

```
{"California":["NJ","Seattle","NY"],"NJ":["California","Seattle","NY"],"NY":["NJ","Seattle","California"],"Seattle":["NJ","California","NY"]}
```

This data is getting fetched in one line. I ultimately need to be able to access the keys as sources and the array of values as possible destinations in Pig.

I tried few ways to load this data using JsonLoader, elephantbird JSON loader, but it kept returning blanks instead of the data.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

JsonLoader expects a predefined schema to be present unlike what you have. How big is your dataset? If it is not all that big, you are better off writing a simple python / Java UDF which takes the entire json string, converts into a bag of tuples that you want. In your pig script, just call this UDF and call `FLATTEN` on the bag returned by it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have never written any UDFs before so was trying to check for alternate approaches if available. The data won't be very big. Are you aware of any existing UDFs which I could try and tweak?

Comment: Writing UDFs are very easy. You should look at documentation and simple tutorial / examples which explain the same in detail: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/udf.html. There are many json libraries in java that you can use if you are writing Java UDF. Python has a json library that you need to import to do the same

Comment: I am unsure of what data type should this be mapped-to in Java to finally be able to get all the sources as keys and all the respective destinations. I have to use these values in the script to build the logic further. Given the urgency, I wanted to check if anyone has done this before.

Comment: would there be an easier way to load this data if it were in the following form:
`{"src":"California", "dest":["NJ","Seattle","NY"],
"src":"NJ", "dest":["California","Seattle","NY"],
"src":"NY", "dest":["NJ","Seattle","California"],
"src":"Seattle", "dest":["NJ","California","NY"]}`

Comment: it would be easier if it was in form {"src":"California", "dest":["NJ","Seattle","NY"]}\n{"src":"NJ", "dest":["California","Seattle","NY"], "src":"NY", "dest":["NJ","Seattle","California"]}\n{"src":"Seattle", "dest":["NJ","California","NY"]} - in that case you could just use JsonLoader('src:chararray, dest:{(state:chararray)}')

Comment: I tried the format suggested by you, but it is returning only the src part, the dest fields are returned as blanks in the dump. Do I need to process those further?